# Entity Framework .NET Exclude Soft Deleted Records from the Table when loaded into the model

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a table shown below:

[image]

In this table a records can be soft deleted by setting the Deleted On field to the date of deletion.

However I want to ensure the model excludes this record when refreshed. The records will still be in the database, but not accessible from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to filter the data using where clause

```
var entity = dbContext.ExerciseType
                  .Where(x.C_DeletedOn != null).SingleOrDefault();
```

Another way, you can set GlobalFilters on the entity in OnModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourTableHere>().HasQueryFilter(YourConditionHere);
```

Comment: At what point is the Sub OnModelCreating called?

Comment: I initiate the model as follow:

Comment: Public MyFitModel As MyFitEntities

    Public Sub RefreshModel()

        MyFitModel = Nothing
        MyFitModel = New MyFitEntities()


    End Sub